# Creating nodes and relationships in Neo4j in the same query from JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, neo4j

Suppose I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            name: "1",
            description: "Node 1",
            parent: ""
        },
        {
            name: "2",
            description: "Node 2",
            parent: "1"
        },
        {
            name: "3",
            description: "Node 3",
            parent: "1"
        },
        {
            name: "4",
            description: "Node 4",
            parent: "3"
        },
    ]
}
```

I wish to create the nodes and the relationships in the same query using `neo4j-driver` for Node.js. Suppose I have that JSON file loaded in a variable called `data`. I've tried this, but haven't been able to create the relationships:

```
const result = await session.run(`
    UNWIND $nodes AS node
    MERGE (n:Node { name: node.name, description: node.description })
    WITH $nodes AS relationships
    UNWIND relationships AS relationship
    MATCH(c:Node { name: relationship.name }), (p:Node { name: relationship.parent })
    MERGE (p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(n)
`, { nodes: data });
```

I get two relationships from 1 to a null node and from 2 to a null node.

Is there any way to do this or should I first create the nodes and then in another query create the relationships.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single run:

```
UNWIND $nodes AS node
MERGE (n:Node { name: node.name })
ON CREATE SET n.description = node.description
FOREACH ( i IN (CASE WHEN node.parent<>'' THEN [1] ELSE [] END) |
     MERGE (p:Node { name: node.parent }) 
     MERGE (p)-[:PARENT_OF]->(n)
)
```